# issue with flutter firebase login

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, persistent

I recently made things work with the login/register module on my app but there are 2 things that are not working:

- first when I register it's ok, I can see in my Firebase Console that the app is creating a new user so that's fine. However, when I try to log in with a user that doesn't exist it still makes me go to the homepage.
- no idea how to make a persistent login, like someone who log in and someone who register when they close the app and then restart the app they should be able to keep the login and then logout if they want.

CAN ANYBODY HELP??

I leave here the code:

**MAIN**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/intro_screen.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color(0xfff2f9fe),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
          disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: IntroScreen(),
      routes: {
        'intro': (context) => IntroScreen(),
        'home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        'login': (context) => AuthScreen(authType: AuthType.login),
        'register': (context) => AuthScreen(authType: AuthType.register),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**AUTH_PAGE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/auth.dart';
import 'package:sport_app/original_button.dart';


class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthType authType;

  const AuthForm({Key key, @required this.authType}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email = '', _password = '';
  AuthBase authBase = AuthBase();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter your email',
                hintText: 'ex: test@gmail.com',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                _email = value;
              },
              validator: (value) =>
              value.isEmpty ? 'You must enter a valid email' : null,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter your password',
              ),
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _password = value;
              },
              validator: (value) => value.length <= 6
                  ? 'Your password must be larger than 6 characters'
                  : null,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            OriginalButton(
              text: widget.authType == AuthType.login ? 'Login' : 'Register',
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  if (widget.authType == AuthType.login) {
                    await authBase.loginWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home');
                  } else {
                    await authBase.registerWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home');
                  }
//                  print(_email);
//                  print(_password);
                }
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 6),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (widget.authType == AuthType.login) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('register');
                  print(widget.authType);
                } else {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('login');
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                widget.authType == AuthType.login
                    ? 'Don\'t have an account?'
                    : 'Already have an account?',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AUTHBASE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class User {
  final String uid;

  User({@required this.uid});
}

class AuthBase {
  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Future<void> registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> loginWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, mark it as answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

You simply navigate to the homepage, even when the login has not completed successfully, becaus there is no condition logic. Do the navigation only in your authBase class, then you should be fine.

You need to import the FirebaseAuthException before you can use it. Then, you

```
Future<bool> loginWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      if(authResult.user != null) { Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home'); }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      if(e.code == 'wrong-password') { Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Wrong Password"),
    )); } 
      else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') { Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("User not found"),
    )); }
      else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') { Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Invalid E-Mail"),
    )); }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and remove change your widget code to:

```
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  if (widget.authType == AuthType.login) {
    await authBase.loginWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
  } else {
    await authBase.registerWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
  }
}
```

Second Problem:
You could try storing the login credentials in the storage (user flutter_secure_storage package for encryption) after the first login and then retrieve it on App startup to perform login like above

Here is a link for the package you should use to store the credentials

---

[flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

Comment: that's very helpful, thanks!
I'm quite new with coding and I'm studying a lot to make things work. 
I understood half of the bool function (don't know where to write it though) you mentioned above, I mean, I guess I just have to Navigate as I'm navigating to any page in the app so I guess that's ok. 
I've no idea how to handle the login failure though...

For the second problem, I literally know nothing about it so if you have link or a previous post on stack overflow it would help a lot! 
thanks!!

Comment: @PasqualeCapuano i have updated my answer, please mark it as the answer if you think that this helped

Comment: I understood there is a problem with the onPressed function of the OriginalButton but I tried to change 'home' with 'intro' and stil takes me to the home page.
I also created a new page and tried to navigate to a materialpageroute and still didn't work.
p.s. I will definitely mark the answer no problems but I would like to fix this and understand not just copy and paste some code.

Comment: Have you changed the login function to a Future<bool> and return a bool that indicates the state of login (true, false)?

Comment: Mmmh no, so definitely I didn’t understand anything  please help! I’m banging my head on the wall 

Comment: Can you add the Code from authBase to your question please? I will then provide you with an explanation + example code on what you should do?

Comment: hi, any help with this??

Comment: @PasqualeCapuano hi, sorry for the long wait, i have updated my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks again for helping. I modified the loginWithEmailAndPassword but still have errors. FirebaseAuthException is underlined in red and when you write between parenthesis "navigate to" or "handlewrong password" etc, it's something I can't do. 
Trying to also understand how but I don't know where to get the information and you were the only one to reply so thanks for that but I need more help as I'm a beginner, trying to learn from scratch

Comment: @PasqualeCapuano i have updated my answer, fel free to ask more questiosn about it :)